# Non-vanishing forms of all degress

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

We know if a manifold admits a non-vanishing n-form, it can be oriented. How about an n-manifold which has non-vanishing forms up to and including n. What kinds of properties would such a manifold have?

Comment: A symplectic manifold is endowed with a nowhere zero $2$-form all of whose powers are non-zero (up to the dimension of the manifold, of course) That gives examples of manifolds with nowhere-zero forms in half the dimensions. Paralellizable manifolds give examples in which you hace nowhere zero forms in all degrees.

Comment: In any case, «what kind of properties such a manifold has?» is a wildly inespecific question...

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez  for example does it have to be paralellizable? Do such manifolds have some interesting properties? These are very reasonable questions to ask in mathematics, I think. Thanks anyway. The symplictic was interesting.

Comment: Take any orientable closed 3-dimensional manifold $M$. Its Euler characteristic is zero because of Poincaré duality, and there is [therefore](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129752/does-a-connected-manifold-with-vanishing-euler-characteristic-admit-a-nowhere-va) a nowhere zero vector field $X$ on $M$. Now pick a riemannian metric on $M$, and using the isomorphism it gives you between fields and 1-forms, construct from $X$ a nowhere zero $1$-form. The Hodge dual of this $1$-form is also nowhere zero, and it is a $2$-form. Your class of manifolds thus contains all 3-dim closed orientable ones

Comment: I doubt there is any sensible property common to all 3-dim closed orientable manifolds.

Comment: well they are three dimensional...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well they are of course all parallelizable...

Comment: @PVAL, yes, but proving that they are parallelizable is **considerably** more complicated that the trivial argument I sketched — I doubt you can do it without obstruction theory and what not.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez My point was that it was a sensible property common to all 3-dimensional closed or'd manifolds.

Comment: Since clearly begin three-dimensional is not a consequence of having nowhere zero forms in all degrees, that's slightly irrelevant :-)

Comment: So I am confused now. I tell you what I hoped. I thought manifolds which have non vanishing forms of all degrees are "almost" parallelizable; meaning we need a couple of more conditions like they are closed, they must be of dimension so and so and get parallelizable. Nothing like that guys right?